# Error Installing OpenVPN TAP

Tags: windows-7, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to install OpenVPN (2.2.2) on a Windows 7 Professional x64 machine. When I run the installer, I receive an error saying it can't install TAP. The same when running the batch file.

My attempts to resolve this have been:

1. Run as administrator
2. Run on a different admin account
3. Run in compatibility mode as Vista with admin privilages

Any ideas on how the issue can be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

It's discussed here: http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=27589.0 - the two solutions are to either use an older OpenVPN or to turn off the driver signing requirement in Windows. Haven't tested personally. Found this looking for a solution to a different problem.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Its not good to give the link only here please include the essential part of the article which could be a solution to OP and give the link as reference :)